# Cannot import behave.given in pydev for django

Tags: python, django, pydev, python-behave

I have a Django project for which I am incorporating BDD using behave. I am using PyDev as my development environment. I have installed behave_dhango and behave using pip within the conda environment and I can see that the folders have been created in the site-packages folder within the right conda 'env'.

For some reason, I am not able to import the 'given, when and then' decorators from behave as thus:

```
    from behave import given, when, then
```

It says "Unresolved import given... when... and then..."

I have not found any naming conflicts and cannot understand the reason why the above code isn't working.

Python 2.7
Django 1.11
behave 1.2.6

Comment: Did you add `behave_django`  into *settings.INSTALLED_APPS*

Comment: Thanks, Waket. Yes... It is set in the INSTALLED_APPS... But not having it set shouldn't stop me from importing within another, should it?

Comment: If you add `behave` to the forced builtins, does it work? (see http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html#PyDevInterpreterConfiguration-ForcedBuiltins for details on how to do that).

Comment: @Fabio, adding 'behave' to the forced builtins worked like a charm... Thanks for your help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you add behave to the forced builtins, does it work? (see pydev.org/… for details on how to do that). – Thanks to [Fabio Zadrozny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/110451/fabio-zadrozny)

Answer (score 0):

Have you set the interpreter of PyDev?

http://www.pydev.org/manual_101_interpreter.html

Comment: I had set it up, @Waket... The issue was solved by adding 'behave' to forced built-in list..